Multivariable inverse function theorem-doubt regarding proof of auxiliary lemma
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable on some open set which contains the point $a$, and suppose $Df(a)$ is invertible, i.e. det$D(a)\neq 0$. Then there exists an open set $V$ which contains $a$ and an open set $W$ which contains $f(a)$ such that $f:V\to W$ has continuos inverse $f^{-1}: W\to V,$ which is differentiable for all $y\in W.$

The proof of this theorem requires the following lemma.
Lemma: Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open rectangle and let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable. If there exists some $M>0$ such that $$\left|\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x)\right|\leq M\;\text{for all}\;x\in A,$$ then
$$||f(y)-f(z)||\leq n^2\cdot M\cdot ||y-z||\;\\
\text{for all}\;y,z\in A.$$

The proof of the lemma goes something like this:
We express $$f_i(y)-f_i(z)\; (1)\\ =f_i(y_1,....,y_n)-f_i(z_1,...,z_n)\; (2)\\
=\sum_{j=1}^{n}[f(y_1,...,y_j,z_{j+1},...,z_n)-f(y_1,...,y_{j-1},z_j,z_{j+1},...,z_n)]\; (3)\\
=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x_{ij})(y_j-z_j)\; (4).$$
Then the proof continues but this is the only part of the proof I'm concerned with right now.
From (3) to (4) I think I have to apply the unidimensional mean value theorem for each $j$, but I cannot see how to go from (2) to (3).
Could someone please enlighten me? I don't want to simply accept this proof without understanding it.

Since $f:A\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector function, we agree that $f(y)-f(z)=(f_1(y)-f_1(z),\dots,f_n(y)-f_n(z))^\top$, where $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)^\top$ and $z=(z_1,\dots,z_n)^\top$. Now, observe that for each $i=1,\dots, n$ we can write:
$$
f_i(y_1,\dots,y_n)-f_i(z_1,\dots,z_n)= \\
\color{blue}{f_i(y_1,z_2,\dots,z_n)}-f_i(z_1,\dots,z_n)+\\
+f(y_1,y_2,z_3,\dots,z_n)-\color{blue}{f_i(y_1,z_2,\dots,z_n)}+\\
\vdots \\
+f_i(y_1,\dots,y_n)-f_i(y_1,\dots,y_{n-1},z_n).
$$
Basically you sum and subtract the same quantities in blue for each position of $j$. This result can be written in compact form as:
$$f_i(y)-f_i(z)=\sum_{j=1}^n\bigl[f_i(y_1,\dots,y_j,z_{j+1},\dots,z_n)-f_i(y_1,\dots,y_{j-1},z_j,\dots,z_n)\bigr].$$
Subsequently, the continuity of the partial derivatives $\partial_jf_i$ gives:
$$f_i(y_1,\dots,y_j,z_{j+1},\dots,z_n)-f_i(y_1,\dots,y_{j-1},z_j,\dots,z_n)=\\
=\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(y_1,\dots,y_{j-1},z_j+\theta_{ij}h_j,z_{j+1},\dots,z_n)h_j,$$
where $h_j=y_j-z_j$ and $\theta_{ij}\in(0,1)$, for all $i,j=1,\dots,n$. Call the vector:
$$x_{ij}=(y_1,\dots,y_{j-1},z_j+\theta_{ij}h_j,z_{j+1},\dots,z_n)^\top$$
to find:
$$
f_i(y)-f_i(z)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x_{ij})h_j.
$$
The rest of the proof follows.

Let $g:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ have $|\partial_i g|\leq M$. Then $|\nabla g| \leq \sqrt n M$. Set $\varphi(t) = g(tx+(1-t)y)$. By the Schwarz inequality and the chain rule, $|\varphi'(t)|\leq \sqrt n M |x-y|$. The fundamental theorem of calculus gives
$$|g(x)-g(y)| = |\varphi(1)-\varphi(0)| \leq \int_0^1 |\varphi'(t)|dt \leq \sqrt n M|x-y|\,.$$
Applying this to each of the functions $f_i$ gives
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq nM|x-y|\,, $$
so your lemma exhibits the incorrect scaling (though this doesn't matter since your dimension is fixed).
